# Поменять столбцы матрицы местами в numpy

Tags: python, numpy

К примеру есть матрица вида:

```
X = np.array([
    [1,2],
    [1,2],
    [1,2]
])
```

Нужно поменять столбцы местами, что бы стало вот так:

```
X = np.array([
    [2,1],
    [2,1],
    [2,1]
])
```

Из идей приходит только вот это:

```
X[:,0], X[:,1] = X[:,1], X[:,0].copy()
```

Возможно ли то же самое сделать средствами numpy ? (долго искал ничего сам не нашел)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20265477/7927226 - может быть полезно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [88]: X = X[:, ::-1]

In [89]: X
Out[89]:
array([[2, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 1]])
```

можно воспользоваться функцией [np.flip(..., axis=1)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html):

```
In [93]: X = np.flip(X, axis=1)

    In [94]: X
    Out[94]:
    array([[2, 1],
           [2, 1],
           [2, 1]])
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, пожалуйста :)